# Rails and webpacker: accessing Javascript modules in Rails actions (show.js.erb)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I'm running an application that was converted from Rails 5.2 to Rails 6, and I'm trying to convert the JS from the asset pipeline to webpacker.

I'm using Rails UJS via webpacker to execute remote AJAX requests which are supposed to receive and execute the javascript code sent back from the server.

From [Rails edge docs](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#server-side-concerns):

> Notice the format.js in the respond_to block: that allows the
>   controller to respond to your Ajax request. You then have a
>   corresponding app/views/users/create.js.erb view file that generates
>   the actual JavaScript code that will be sent and executed on the
>   client side.
>
> `$("<%= escape_javascript(render @user) %>").appendTo("#users");`

This is how I have it setup.

```
# app/views/users/index.html.erb
<%= link_to "New", new_user_path, remote: true %>
```

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def new
  @user = User.new
  # defaults response to new.js.erb
end
```

```
# app/views/users/new.js.erb
Dialog.showDialog("<%=j render('form') %>");
```

When Rails UJS executes the `users/new` action, it's supposed to execute the JS code that gets returned.  However, since webpacker uses es6 modules, I'm assuming Rails UJS doesn't know anything about the `Dialog` JS class.

How do I inform Rails UJS about this class so it can execute the JS code response?

This was fully functional with the Rails asset pipeline, and I think it's because all the JS classes were added to the global namespace (ie, `Dialog` wasn't hidden behind any module).

I'm trying to convert it to webpacker, and keep running into `Uncaught ReferenceError: Dialog is not defined` errors.

```
# app/javascript/packs/application.js
import Dialog from "dialog"
```

```
# app/javascript/dialog.js
export default class Dialog {
  static showDialog(html) {
    ...JS to create and append element to body then show, etc...
  }
}
```

```
# config/webpack/environment.js
const { environment } = require("@rails/webpacker")
const webpack = require("webpack")

// Put into global namespace instead of importing in every file you use it.
environment.plugins.prepend("Provide",
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    Rails: ["@rails/ujs"],
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery"
  })
)
```

How do you follow the example code in the Rails edge guides anymore?  It seems that using webpacker and modules in this case breaks that example.

I've been able to address parts of my use-case by executing vanilla JS from the server and thus not needing my `Dialog` class defined.

```
# app/views/users/new.js.erb 
document.body.appendChild(
  document.createRange().createContextualFragment("<%=j render 'form' %>")
)
```

But even then I would want to create some sort of utility class to abstract and shorten this to something like:

```
Util.appendToBody("<%=j render 'form' %>")
```

which is right back where I started, trying to access a `Util` class that is not accessible because it is scoped in an es6 module.

Comment: This is a stretch, but did you find a way to do this? I'm wanting to do the same thing. Afaik, there's no way to do it, but I figured I'd ask, just in case.

Comment: @dkniffin: my solution was to have global JS classes that I attach to the `window` object: `import Global from "classes/global"` `window.Global = Global`. That allows me to reference `Global.someMethod()` in my `js.erb` files. So technically "no" I didn't find a clean ES6 module solution, but this global works well for me. I don't think absolute modularity is a benefit whenever code needs to talk to each other.

Comment: I believe that [this](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader) is what you were looking for